# Debugging Xamarin Views

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to figure out why my Xamarin Android code doesn't work. I've been modifying the [default](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/) Hello World app.  In `Main.axml` I added

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/RandomButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Random" />
```

and sure enough, inside `MainActivity.OnCreate()` this will compile:

```
 Button button = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.RandomButton);
```

But, `button` is null. There must be something very basic and obvious that I'm doing wrongly, although I can't figure out what.

Comment: Are you loading your Layout via `SetContentView` **before** using `FindViewById`?

Comment: Yes. 

        `protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);            
            Button button = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.RandomButton);
            if (button != null)
            {
                button.Click += delegate
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.s0011).Start();
                };
            }`

is  my code. The button shows up on the screen, it just doesn't do anything.  Breaking reveals that it's null.